# Signalr Hub & PersistentConnection code difference

Tags: signalr, persistent, signalr-hub

i am bit familiar with Signalr using Signalr Hub approach. when we create communication program using Signalr Hub then we write the code like this way

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
```

and client side we connect to hub using this way with javascript like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and when we write communication program using PersistentConnection then code looks like

```
public class MyConnection : PersistentConnection
{
    protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
    {
        string msg = string.Format(
            "A new user {0} has just joined. (ID: {1})",
            request.QueryString["name"], connectionId);
        return Connection.Broadcast(msg);
    }
    protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
    {
        // Broadcast data to all clients
        string msg = string.Format(
            "{0}: {1}", request.QueryString["name"], data);
        return Connection.Broadcast(msg);
    }
}
```

**client side for connecting**

```
$(function () {
            $("#join").click(function () {
                var connection = $.connection("/echo", "name=" + $("#name").val(), true);;

                connection.received(function (data) {
                    addMsg(data);
                });
                connection.error(function (err) {
                    addMsg("Error: " + err);
                });

                addMsg("Connecting...");
                connection.start(function () {
                    addMsg("Connected.");
                    $("#send").click(function () {
                        connection.send($("#msg").val());
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

now when anyone see the code for develop any communication apps with HUB or PersistentConnection  then they definitely notice there are different approach to connect to hub or PersistentConnection  at server end from client side through javascript.

when we connect to hub from client side then we write javscript like this way

```
// Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
```

here we declare the proxy like this way in case of hub. connection and then my hub name whatever i gave.

but in case of PersistentConnection we declare proxy like this way

```
var connection = $.connection("/echo", "name=" + $("#name").val(), true);
```

my question is why we do not have to give our class name which extend PersistentConnection class like this way `public class MyConnection : PersistentConnection`
rather our code should look like

```
var connection = $.connection.MyConnection ("/echo", "name=" + $("#name").val(), true);
```

also tell me what is echo ?
also guide me why do i need to pass user as query string ?

just guide me why so we need to write code differently when we use hub or PersistentConnection ? thanks